# Shopify theme configuration issue "'theme' is not recognized"

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to create a shopify theme for my store and I am following this video [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCDo-l5DJSo&t=371s&ab_channel=CodingwithRobby)

At 5.43 second he run a command line which is `theme configure -s quickstart-c160a854.myshopify.com -t 154983334208 -p ...` and I get an error which says :'theme' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any idea how I can fix that?

I tried removing 'theme' from the command line and then it does not like 'configure'